# At a seder, If each kos has its own pri hagafen bracha, why does the afikoman not have its own al achilat matza bracha?

Tags: halacha, blessing, passover, ashkenazi, afikoman

At an Ashkenazi seder, If each kos has its own pri hagafen bracha, why does the afikoman not have its own al achilat matza bracha?